# Call Controller function from view JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

MVC Noob here.

Basically, I'm trying to call a function that's in an apicontroller. Here's the apicontroller side:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage<String> Recognize(string strokes)
    {
        var strokePointsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strokes);

        var strokeCollection = GetStrokeCollectionFromPoints(strokePointsData);

        var inkAnalyzer = new InkAnalyzer();

        inkAnalyzer.AddStrokes(strokeCollection);

        var analysisStatus = inkAnalyzer.Analyze();

        if (analysisStatus.Successful)
        {
            var recognizedString = inkAnalyzer.GetRecognizedString();
            return new HttpResponseMessage<string>(recognizedString);
        }
        else
            return new HttpResponseMessage<string>("Data not recognized");
    }
```

And here's the JS:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
        $.post('/api/Recognition/Recognize',
               { strokes: JSON.stringify(strokesHistory)},
               function (result) {
                   alert(result);
               });
    });
```

Yet every time I compile and run, I get a `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:1409/api/recognition/recognize"` error message. This tells me that it's looking for an object in the root folder in /api/recognition/recognize, but I don't see any folders like that in the root folder, so this error makes sense. Yet, from all the research I've done, it looks like the URI I have above should be the right context. What am I missing?